# Instance creation

Tags: javascript

```
var Vehicle = function Vehicle() {
 // ...
}

var vehicle = new Vehicle();
```

When new Vehicle() is called, JavaScript does four things:

1. It creates a new object.
2. It sets the constructor property of the object to Vehicle.
3. It sets up the object to delegate to Vehicle.prototype.
4. It calls Vehicle() in the context of the new object.

What is that third point telling? Does it mean new object constructor prototype is set to function.prototype? What does delegate mean here?

Comment: If you want to get an understanding of how object creation/prototypes works and have some time then this is an excellent read [Prototypes in JS](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just consider **delegate** as **reference**, every object has an `[[Prototype]]` internal property, and it references to its **constructor's prorotype**, so:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(vehicle) === Vehicle.prototype; // always true
```

This is a seudo code about what `new` operator is doing:

```
function fakeNew(constructor) {
    var instance = {};
    instance.__proto__ = constructor.prototype;
    instance.constructor = constructor;
    constructor.apply(instance, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that:

```
vehicle.constructor.prototype === Vehicle.prototype; // true
```

So the methods available on `Vehicle.prototype` will be available to the `vehicle` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Vehicle = function Vehicle() {
    this.engine = {running:false};
}
Vehicle.prototype.startEngine = function () {
    this.engine.running = true;
};

var vehicle1 = new Vehicle();
vehicle.startEngine();
// vehicle.engine.running === true
var vehicle2 = new Vehicle();
vehicle2.startEngine = function () {
    throw "err";
};
vehicle2.startEngine();
// Error: "err"
```

Javascript is prototype based, so every object inherits from another object (prototype).
When you call a property on an object, it first searches the property in its own scope, if it can't find it, goes up in the property chain.